# Filter By Value in Specific Cell

Tags: vba, excel, filter

I have an Excel macro that filters data by certain values.  The code I'm using is below.

```
Sheet6.Select
   ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$E$2000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="2249"
```

I want it to filter for the value in a cell rather than the hardcoded "2249."  I've tried making cell references like RANGE and CELLS, but that hasn't worked.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Store value of cell into variable then use that as criteria?

Comment: That worked perfectly.  Easy solution.  Thank you very much.  I did notice that for some reason, when I defined the variable using Range, it didn't work, but when I used Cells it did.  I'm not sure why that is, but I have the solution now.  Thanks again.

Comment: `Sheet6.Range("$A$1:$E$2000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Sheet6.Range("G1")` should work, you won't need an additional variable if you can directly specify the range where the value is stored (in this case *G1* on the same sheet).